# Uncaught TypeError when using Google API JavaScript Client

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing a simple Tic Tac Toe on Google App engine using cloud endpoints. My API name is tictactoe2D. 
I have only 1 endpoint method by the name tictactoe2D.compute2DMove() in my API which I have tested in the APIs explorer, and is working absolutely fine.

Now I am working to create the front end of the game, and using Google APIs JavaScript Client library to communicate with my endpoint method. I have followed exactly the same procedure as shown in the [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) page, which is a complete tutorial on using the library.

Here is code snippet from board.html, **which loads the Javascript library-**

```
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe 3D</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8" content="text/html"/>

    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=onLoadCallback"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLoadCallback()   {
           gapi.client.setApiKey('AIzaSyB7p7mH_vZGgtrbF4ntmKN2nBcsRyRFY1w');
           gapi.client.load('tictactoe2D', 'v1');   
       }
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/render.js"></script>
</head>
```

And here is the code from render.js, **which add the functionality to deal with click event of all squares, and also communicates with my endpoint method-**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#board td").click(function() {
        $(this).html("X");

        var boardString = [];
        var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('td');
        for (var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++)    {
            boardString.push(buttons[i].innerHTML);
        }

        boardString.join('');

        gapi.client.tictactoe2D.compute2DMove({'state': boardString}).execute(function(resp)    {
            document.write(resp.result.state);
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p55duj18/) for the whole code.

**Problem occurs when I try to click one of the squares on the game board. Unexpectedly, nothing happens.**
I opened up the JavaScript console in Chrome, and found out that the console showed the following error whenever I click on a square-

```
       Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'compute2DMove' of undefined
```

I have not been able to figure out why is this happening, and how can I fix it. Can anybody please help me out?
Thankyou very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up fixing the bug myself after I observing a new error on the JS console- The error was-

```
Failed to load resource: The server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

I checked the JSON object that the server returned, and the object was something like this-

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"sslRequired","message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}],"code":403,"message":"SSL is required to perform this operation."}}
```

After seeing this, I guessed that a secure connection(HTTPS) was not used to connect to the app, and that is why server was not loading the required data. To fix this, I needed to mandate that a secure connection be used every time the app is loaded. **For this, I added the following  tag to web.xml**-

```
<security-constraint>
   <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I updated my app on appspot, and checked the JS console. **There was no error there, and my endpoint method executed too.** I hope this information if helpful to anyone who faces a similar issue.

Also, I found out that the `gapi` library had some stability issues in the past, **and the best way to safeguard your API calls against any possible flaws is to construct a REST request using** `gapi.client.request()`, **instead on making JSON-RPC requests.** (see, [Constructing REST requests using gapi.client.request)](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#Option2usegapiclientrequest). Constructing REST requests might be lengthy and cumbersome, but is safe too.